# Sort data by date & time and then select the next min date to update the other date column in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, teradata-sql-assistant

**Have Data like this** This is a teradata table which is my source in informatica

```
 S_ID      A_ID     START_DATE          END_DATE      STATUS

   1          a         01-02-2017         01-03-2017     CLOSED

   1          a         01-03-2017         31-12-9999     CLOSED       

   1          b         01-04-2017         31-12-9999     CLOSED

   1          c         01-05-2017         31-12-9999     ACTIVE
```

**Now my requirement is this set of data below:** how can i use or modify my source table to get the below results which is also a table in Teradata (i can also use a sqloverride in source qualifier)

```
 S_ID      A_ID     START_DATE          END_DATE      STATUS

   1          a         01-02-2017         01-03-2017     CLOSED

   1          a         01-03-2017         01-04-2017     CLOSED       

   1          b         01-04-2017         01-05-2017     CLOSED

   1          c         01-05-2017         31-12-9999     ACTIVE
```

Comment: we dont know what is your problem?  so specify more your question?

Comment: I just want to update my END_DATE with the START_DATE of the next min(START_DATE) available and no need to touch the END_DATE if the STATUS IS active or for the max (START_DATE) that too for the same S_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an expression transformation to feed the END_DATE which is sent out i.e. using an IIF statement in the END_DATE_OUT port:

```
IIF(STATUS = 'CLOSED', ADD_TO_DATE(START_DATE, 'MM', 1), END_DATE)
```